# Webalizer database error

Tags: webalizer

Webalizer stops to generate statistics.

When I try to check database i see:

```
# webalizer --db-info

Stone Steps Webalizer v3.10.2.5 (Linux 4.6.4-grsec-zfs+)

Using database /home/www/1/statystyka/webalizer.db
Reading history file... /home/www/1/statystyka/webalizer.hist
Cannot find the last URL (ID: 752154) of an active visit (ID: 3)
Saving history information...
```

When I do it on other site I see:

```
# webalizer --db-info

Stone Steps Webalizer v3.10.2.5 (Linux 4.6.4-grsec-zfs+)

Using database /home/www/2/statystyka/webalizer.db
Reading history file... /home/www/2/statystyka/webalizer.hist
Creating output in /home/www/2/statystyka

Database        : /home/www/2/statystyka/webalizer.db
Created by      : 3.10.2.5
Last updated by : 3.10.2.5
First day       : 2017/12/01
Log time        : 2017/12/27 01:18:15
Active visits   : 2
Active downloads: 0
Incremental     : yes
Batch           : no

Maintenance time is 0.00 seconds
Total run time is 0.00 seconds
Saving history information...
```

I tried to run `webalizer --end-month` but it failed.

How to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix:

Get webalizer database from backup before damage and rebuild database using log:

```
/usr/local/sbin/webalizer -c /etc/webalizer/webalizer-1.conf -q -T /var/log/apache/1.access.log
```